# How can I open more than 15 files at once on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

How can I open more than fifteen files on Windows 7 at once? I can do fifteen by selecting them and pressing enter, but if I try to select more, enter stops doing anything.

All the files are the same type — pictures.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't.

Comment: @KContreau: Is it different for different kinds of files?

Comment: all the files are the same type -pictures

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, if the files are all opened by the same program, they can be opened by selecting them all and hitting enter, or right-clicking and hitting open. If they are not opened using the same program, you can't, and the open menu item won't be there when right-clicking.

Comment: Are they all opened with the same program?

Comment: when i right click it does not give me the option to Open(by 16+ files)is that wierd?

Comment: @chabad Ahh, I understand the problem now. There is a limit. I will see if I can find a regisrty entry that breaks that limit. I was able to put 16 .jpg files in a folder, and if I click 15, the open menu is there, but click all 16, and no menu item.

Comment: This behavior is by design.  Versions of Windows before Vista would return a warning dialog stating that the computer may stop responding if the user attempts to open too many files at once.  See also this question: http://superuser.com/questions/58080/open-more-than-15-files-at-once-on-vista.  The behavior is the same in Windows 7 as it is in Windows Vista, so this could be considered a possible duplicate (though not exact).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Open regedit and navigate to:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

Add this case-sensitive DWORD (32-bit) key:

```
MultipleInvokePromptMinimum
```

Set the value to

```
16
```

P.S. 16 is not a hard number, but actually indicates "unlimited", so putting in 17 probably will not work.

Comment: +1 you just pwned me. :) Nice answer, this is actually very useful! Hope you get lots of upvotes!

Comment: can i put in whatever number instead of 16?

Comment: @chabad Actually, if you read the last line, I just edited my answer a few minutes ago to address that exact question.

Comment: Based on some of the (now deleted) non-answers below, it's worth pointing out that you apparently need to type the `16` in hexidecimal mode, not in binary mode. There should be a radio button to select hex/dec when you enter the value.

Comment: The value of the number does matter, at least on my setup of Windows 7. If I set mine to 50, I can open that many songs at once, but cannot open 51.

Comment: 16 does not indicate unlimited, it just indicates the hex value of 16, because while you were entering it the radio button for *hexadecimal* was checked by default.16 in hex is 22, so the limit when following this answer would be 22.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, it may be possible to use the *File* | *Open* dialog and select all the files (e.g. Microsoft Excel)

It could be more efficient too as the application will know best how to deal with the files (e.g. single instance / multiple instances, open them in a particular order, etc.)