# Enable 'Open With' for more than one file

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, right-click

I try to open more than one picture to photoshop but there is no option for 'Open With' as it does for one picture (jpg).

I found several options on the internet such [this](https://superuser.com/questions/300911/how-can-i-open-more-than-15-files-at-once-on-windows-7) and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2022295), and some more such as [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/178066-open-add-program.html), but I prefer regedit approach and none has served me.

*PS. When I drag&drop all the pictures into the app, it works as expected; opening each image into a different worksheet. However, if there a worksheet is already open, this doesn' work, in stead it loads all pictures into the same worksheet (such as different layers).*

Comment: Why was this question tagged as Windows 7 and Windows 10?  Why don't you just set a default application for the file extension, then just open the files, works for me in my test cases.

Comment: because this occurs in both versions. I already tried what you prompt me to do, but there is another problem. I need jpg files to open with a simple jpg viewer such as Windows Photo Viewer and edit them in Photoshop. Can you imagine loading Photoshop each time I want check the pictures?

Comment: I'm confused.  There is a "regedit approach" in the as the answer to the first link you posted.  By "none has served me" do you mean none of the registry solutions you've found have worked for you?

Comment: yes, I tried these approaches but they don't work; they serve for other cases, not mine.